# With out AWS access key & secrect AWS services not working(IAM Role associated)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

It was working with out security credentials, I did composer update, and its updated  new PHP SDK version.
My AWS services stop working, If i provide security credentials its start working.

Ec2 instance associated with IAM Role, I don't want to expose security credentials.

- Removing aws/aws-sdk-php (3.70.0)
- Installing aws/aws-sdk-php (3.75.0)
  Downloading: 100%
- Removing aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel (3.2.1)
- Installing aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel (3.3.0)
  Downloading: 100%

This release worked.

Comment: It worked with the new release.                                                                                 

 - Removing aws/aws-sdk-php (3.70.0)
 - Installing aws/aws-sdk-php (3.75.0)
   Downloading: 100%

 - Removing aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel (3.2.1)
 - Installing aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel (3.3.0)
   Downloading: 100%

Answer (score 0):

It worked with the new release. - Removing aws/aws-sdk-php (3.70.0) - Installing aws/aws-sdk-php (3.75.0)